# What is the best branching strategy for DB/ETL development in GIT

Tags: sql-server, git, branch

My new team uses GIT and they use a 'centralized workflow', which I am strongly against.  We are database/SSIS developers, there is **no app development**. I worked for 2 years in GIT prior to this the gitflow/feature branching strategy and it worked perfectly. I have been trying to explain why each dev only having one branch as their workspace is not good practice...bad for traceability, and not really utilizing the full capability of GIT.  Why not just use SVN? Can anyone provide some info/documentation/anything to help my argument on why each dev only re-using their same branch each time is not good practice? Would really appreciate it.  I've found some content online but I'd love to hear other DB/ETL devs' opinions on the best branching strategy for database/etl (ssis) development for a team of 5 devs.

This is not an opinion-based question. What if Dev 1 wants to work on Story/feature A and they aren't done yet with their current work and all of a sudden they need to fix a bug that takes higher priority? Traceability is lost if it's done this way. To me, that's the biggest issue. I'm looking for other reasons why this practice is not recommended. I don't see why you wouldn't use a branch for each story/feature/item of work.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Git gets traceability and a concurrency version system. Also, with SVN you can get similar targets but you'll need an add-in like dbForge to get special power commands. By another hand, if:

1. You don't want to complex any task
2. Your development team are working with SSIS and Microsoft SQL Server
3. Your requirements in such projects change often.
4. You have several projects which are being run in parallel involve the same codebase.
   Then, you may redirect to Team Foundation Server (TFS) which has basic functions like checking, checkout, branching and merging and they work fine for MS Win server environments.